# what is wrong here? The printf gives an error

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class AssignClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numArr[] = {82,60,72,50,3,39,47,20}; //integer array 
        int smallTemp = numArr[0]; //assigning zeroth element as small number
        int largeTemp = numArr[1]; //assigning first element as large number

        for(int i=0; i<numArr.length;i++) //iterating till the end of the array
        {
            if(largeTemp<numArr[i]) //check if i'th value of array is large than largeTemp
            {
                largeTemp=numArr[i];
            }
            if(smallTemp>numArr[i]) //check if i'th value of array is small than largeTemp
            {
                smallTemp=numArr[i]; 
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Largest Number: %d\n", largeTemp); //print large number
        System.out.printf("Smallest Number: %d\n", smallTemp); //print small number

    }

}
```

The printf is underlined in red and gives and error? What is wrong? I used Eclipse

Comment: ... what is the error?

Comment: Have you tried ... compiling the code?

Comment: This code works for me, make sure you hve JDK in your classpath.

Comment: By the way, the issue may be in your initialisation of numArr. You should do something like: `int[] numArr = new int[] {}` if you want to create and initialise the array using literal values in one statement.

Comment: @user268396 that compiles fine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right: the initialization is the long way of creating arrays for when you know the values ahead of time. Would it have anything to do with decimal formatting an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is available since Java 5., so looks like your project is configured to use Java 1.4. Change the configuration of your project by right clicking on it, then go to Properties:

- Select Java Build Path option and make sure you're using the proper Java JDK version for your project.
- Select Java Compiler option and make sure you're using Java 1.5 or superior.

If you happen to create a project in Java 8, make sure you're using Eclipse Luna or Eclipse Kepler with the plugin for Java 8 support. IMO I recommend you to use Eclipse Luna. DISCLAIMER: I'm not contributor of Eclipse or any other Eclipse-base technology, just a happy user of this tool.